# How can I write accuracy and precision values side by side?

Tags: python, syntax, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNM1N.png)How can I print precision, accuracy, recall and f1-score values side by side as shown in the image ?

```
for name, model in models:
model = model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
from sklearn import metrics
print("Model -> %s -> \n ACCURACY[enter image description here][1]: %%%.2f" % (name,metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred)*100), end=" -> ")
print("Model -> %s -> PRECISION: %%%.2f" % (name,metrics.precision_score(Y_test, Y_pred)*100,), end=" -> ")
print("Model -> %s -> RECALL: %%%.2f" % (name,metrics.recall_score(Y_test, Y_pred)*100,), end=" -> ")
print("Model -> %s -> F1-SCORE: %%%.2f" % (name,metrics.f1_score(Y_test, Y_pred)*100,))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "side by side"? On the same line?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [*formatted string literals*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) (also called f-strings for short), that is, string literals with 'f' or 'F' in their prefixes:

```
>>> name = 'Oliver'
>>> last_name = 'Mohr'
>>> print(f'My name is {name} {last_name}.')
My name is Oliver Mohr.
```

**In general:** Add an `f` before the string as `f'...'`, then you write your string within the `''` symbols and add variables within it inside `{}` braces

Comment: I couldn't do it

Comment: Check out the edited answer on the use of formatted string literals (f-strings)